# Ball and socket joint's Jacobian matrix?

Tags: 3d, inverse-kinematics, skeletal-animation

I'm trying to apply one of the IK methods, which is using the pseudo inverse of a jacobian matrix to my human skeleton I made in OpenGL. I've been using the following link,
https://www.math.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/ResearchWeb/ikmethods/iksurvey.pdf

and I learned that the calculations of the entries of the Jacobian Matrix is fairly simple (page 5 of the link), using the equation

[image]

However, this equation is only when there's one DOF, and the rotation axis is v_j. For the case of 3 DOFs like the ball and socket joint, how do I set the entries of the Jacobian matrix?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It's exactly the same. Just that you have 3 dofs now (corresponding to three separate columns in the Jacobian).

Comment: @Nico Schertler Thanks!!